# App crashes without error on expo router push on android but works on web

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I have the following app directory structure

[image]

I have used this code to open course detail screen
`router.push({ pathname: "coursedetail/[id]", params: { id: course.id, }, });` 
this works fine
from course detail screen I have a button to jump to Instructor detail  using the following push code.
`const handlePress = () => { router.push({ pathname: "instructordetails/[id]", params: { id: courseTeacher.id, purpose: purpose, }, }); };`
when I execute this the app screen disappears with no error in the log, when I even try to check it using adb logcat
there is no crash error. please help me I am stuck here.

I try to write try and catch block or I even tried to use adb logcat but no error is provided, the app simply closed or crashed.